# How can I clone an svn repository that changed layouts with git maintaining full history?

Tags: git, svn

## Problem

I want to clone an svn repo with git-svn.
The problem is the subversion repository changed layouts at `r1235`.

## Specifics

From revision 1 to 1234, `foo` used the standard svn folder layout with:

- /trunk/src
- /tags/`version`/src

At revision 1235, the author added `bar` to the repo. To do so they restructured the master repository making the folder layout look like this:

- /trunk/foo/src
- /trunk/bar/src
- /tags/`version`/foo/src
- /tags/`version`/bar/src

## Goal

I want a new git repository that has the history of `foo` as if it was never rearranged to include `bar`.

## Relevant Documentation

Working with non standard layouts is discussed in git-svn's documentation.

If the entire history in unnecessary (or if I just want `bar`), I can get what I want from r1235 on:

- `git svn init --stdlayout http://path.to/repo`
- edit `repo/.git/config` adding `/foo` to relevant paths (or `/bar`)

`

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
   url = http://path.to/repo
   fetch = trunk/foo:refs/remotes/trunk
   branches = branches/*/foo:refs/remotes/*
   tags = tags/*/foo:refs/remotes/tags/*
```

`

- `git svn fetch -r 1235:HEAD`

## My attempts

- `git svn clone -r 1:1234 --stdlayout http://path.to/repo`
- edit `repo/.git/config` as above
- `git svn fetch -r 1235:HEAD`

## Result

The last command seems to succeed because `r1235` - `HEAD` get downloaded. However, `git log` only shows commits up to `1234`. The working directory also seems to be the old revision.

Comment: You have done it. You just forgot to check out the latest revision; `git svn fetch` does not do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did just `git svn fetch`, so you now have to **check out the latest revision**.

Any of `git svn rebase` (hm, I am least certain with this one after the path change, but normally it's what you use; it includes fetch), `git reset --hard trunk` (forcibly discards local changes), `git rebase trunk` (re-applies committed local changes) or `git merge --ff-only trunk` (check there are no local changes) should do and since you don't have local changes yet are equivalent.

Comment: Doh! That was it. `git reset trunk` did it! `git svn rebase` failed with an error I have since forgotten.